# Custom forms in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

We are using SharePoint online (Office 365), we have requirements to build custom forms as the standard new item forms on lists are not very responsive and we require forms to be placed into publishing pages.

I've been looking at the JSOM but it seems like a lot of effort to create a form, and I imagine making the standard SharePoint controls work in custom forms would be difficult (people picker, checkboxes etc).

Is there any guidance on creating custom forms in SharePoint - using JSOM? Or is there a better approach? P.S not allowed to buy Nintex forms!